# Why can I decode a protobuf namespace but not a configmap?

Tags: kubernetes, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to see how far I can get with decoding protobuf as stored in etcd by Kubernetes. I'm running in a weird problem where I can decode most of the protobuf, except for configmaps:

This gives me valid output:

```
etcdctl get /registry/namespaces/default -w protobuf | protoc --decode_raw
```

But this gives me an error:

```
etcdctl get /registry/configmaps/kube-system/coredns -w protobuf | protoc --decode_raw
Failed to parse input.
```

If I do not pipe the output through protoc, it looks like protobuf (lots of readable strings with control characters in between). What am I doing wrong? What's different with regards to a ConfigMap as opposed to other resources? Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Just to say it, this is just for fun, right? Like you know that you should never do this in a real cluster? :D

Comment: "For fun", as in, I was trying to get some ConfigMap data from an etcd cluster belonging to a totally broken Kubernetes setup (not one of ours, just trying to help by saving what was worth saving) and ran into this. Got the data we needed, but this kept bugging me.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should to know:

> Protobufs are raw binary data, and they can contain `NULL bytes`.

As you mentioned you have control characters:

> If I do not pipe the output through protoc, it looks like protobuf (lots of readable strings with control characters in between).

I can't guess what the signs are. However, it is possible that a `NULL byte` might have ended up somewhere. In this situation you will get an error `Failed to parse input.`

If you have only control characters try to store output from `etcdctl get /registry/configmaps/kube-system/coredns -w protobuf` in the variable and the use `printf` command, like this:

```
result=`etcdctl get /registry/configmaps/kube-system/coredns -w protobuf`
printf $result | protoc --decode_raw
```

This could works if you have only control characters. But that proto still could failed to parse with --decode_raw, if you have a NULL byte in the middle of the proto.

Additionally [coderanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78722/coderanger) well mentioned

> Just to say it, this is just for fun, right? Like you know that you should never do this in a real cluster? :D

You can also read more about similar problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52545703/decode-protobuf-binary-getting-failed-to-parse-input), [here](https://protobuf.narkive.com/IP3iV1yn/decode-raw-errors-with-failed-to-parse-input) and [here](https://github.com/nevermoe/protobuf_decoder/issues/5).

Comment: Sadly, none of this solved the issue. What I'm wondering about is whether there's something special that the kube-apiserver does with the configmap data before parsing it as protobuf. As it works on the other resources I tested, I would assume it worked on ConfigMaps as well.

Also, there's more control character in there then NULL bytes, I'm not entirely sure how to decode it all, but I can see in vim things like ^Z and ^@.

Comment: `^@` - it is a symbol of `NULL`. If this symbol is a part of your ConfigMap, it is unable to decode it. `^Z` is an end-of-file character, so may also produce unexpected effects.Try to remove them manually and then decode it. However, it is very possible that the decode will fail again.